# Different hdri mapping values per camera

Tags: camera, hdri

I was wondering if it's possible to create a connection between mapping values for an hdri and the different cameras in a scene.

For example: in a scene with a building I want to make a render of the front and one of the back. If the front camera is active the hdri would have a 0° rotation, and if the back camera is active it would have a 180° rotation.

Comment: You can keyframe HDRI position and render each camera at different points in time, you can also use a single camera and animate both its position and background mapping in sync. You may also setup different scenes with the same objects but different world shaders

Comment: Or use a driver for the coordinates of the HDR so that the position of the camera determines the rotation.